# How to count inputs in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have n inputs.
these inputs are numbers from 1 to 100.
I want to output the number that appears less than the other ones; also if there are two numbers with the same amount of appearance, I want to output the number that is less than the other one.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work!

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n=scanner.nextInt(), max=0 , ans=-1;
int[] counter = new int[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    counter[scanner.nextInt()]+=1;
for(int j=1; j<=100; j++){
    if(counter[j]>max)
        max=counter[j];
}
for (int i=1; i<=max; i++){
    if(counter[i]>0)
        if(ans==-1 || counter[ans]>counter[i] || (counter[ans] == counter[i] && i<ans))
            ans=i;
}
System.out.print(ans);
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

There’s a couple of problems with your code, but the main one is the last `for` loop: You are trying to find the first (ie lowest) number whose counter is equal to `max`, so your loop should be from 1 to n, not 1 to max.

Another problem is if you are using the number, which is in the range 1-n, as your array index, you need an array of size n+1, not n.

Answer (score 0):

I pinched this from another question regarding the title of yours:

i = input.nextInt (); while (i != 0) { counts [i]++; i = input.nextInt (); } That method increments the number at the position of the user input in the counts array, that way the array holds the number of times a number occurs in a specific index, e.g. counts holds how often 3 occurs.

Answer (score 0):

1. `counter` array should contain frequency values for the numbers from 1 to 100 inclusive.
   That is, either a shift by 1 should be used when counting the frequency:

```java
int[] counter = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    counter[scanner.nextInt() - 1]++;
}
```

or 101 may be used as the length of `counter` array thus representing values in the range `[0..100]`, without shifting by 1.

```java
int[] counter = new int[101];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    counter[scanner.nextInt()]++;
}
```

2. The minimal least frequent number can be found in a single loop (assuming that the `counter` length is 101).

```java
int minFreq = 101, answer = -1;
for(int j = 1; j <= 100; j++) {
    if (counter[j] > 0 && counter[j] < minFreq) { // check valid frequency > 0
        minFreq = counter[j];
        answer = j;
    }
}
System.out.println(answer);
```

3. For a wider range of input values (e.g. including negative values) of a relatively small count it is better to use a hashmap instead of a large sparse array.